# Verifying solution of Heat Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-integration, heat-equation, linear-pde

Let $\theta$ be such that $0<\theta<1/2$. Show that $$F(t,x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp[i\tau t-(i\tau)^{1/2}x-(i\tau)^\theta]d\tau$$
defines a $C^\infty$ function in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which solves the homogeneous heat equation $F_t=F_{xx}$. Also show that $F$ can be written as $$\int_{-a-i\infty}^{a+i\infty}\exp[-zt-z^{1/2}x-z^\theta]dz$$
where complex integration is performed over the vertical straight line $\text{Re} z=-a$ where $a>0$. How to proceed with this question ?